# Using 'filledcurves' with fitted data

Tags: gnuplot

I am fitting some data using 'fit', getting f(x) and plotting it just fine. However, in addition to data points and fitted curve, I wanted to add а confidence interval to the plot, so I would need a "stripe" between f(x)-stddev_y and f(x)+stddev_y.

I could do it writing borders f(x)-stddev_y and f(x)+stddev_y into a table, something like this

```
set datafile separator ';'
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) '0706-2007.csv' using 7:8 via a,b
stddev_y = sqrt(FIT_WSSR / (FIT_NDF + 1 ))
set table "1.dat"
plot [10:80] f(x)-sqrt(FIT_WSSR / (FIT_NDF + 1 ))
set table "2.dat"
plot [10:80] f(x)+sqrt(FIT_WSSR / (FIT_NDF + 1 ))
unset table
plot [10:80] '0706-2007.csv' using 7:8 not with points pt 7 ps 1,f(x) not with lines,\
"< paste 1.dat 2.dat | awk '{print $1\";\"$2\";\"$5;}' " using 1:2:3 with filledcurves title sprintf("σ = %.1f",sqrt(FIT_WSSR/(FIT_NDF+1)))
```

but it looks somewhat involved. Is there any more direct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to fill the area that is covered by the uncertainty of the fit. In your simple case of a linear fit this can indeed be easily done with a constant shift factor. One can make use of the special filename `'+'` (see the manual on `special-filename` for details).

```
set datafile separator ';'
f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) '0706-2007.csv' using 7:8 via a,b
stddev_y = sqrt(FIT_WSSR / (FIT_NDF + 1 ))
plot '+' using ($1):(f($1)-stddev_y):(f($1)+stddev_y) with filledcurves
```

If you happen to have a more complicated fit function, you will need to think more carefully what will be the expression for the minimum and maximum value. For that, it might be useful to `set fit errorvariables`, which will save the fit error of `a, b` as `a_err, b_err`

Comment: Ok. I did use a, b and a_err, b_err even in the case of this linear fit.

Comment: Sure, this is of course also fine. If my answer helped you, may I ask you to sign it as accepted answer?